# Is possibile to add values on lines that connect two nodes in organization chart of Google'sChart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I'm using Google's Charts library to create an organization chart. i have to add additional information on the lines that connect the nodes as you can see in the screenshot. Is it possible?

Thank you.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjtSM.png)

Comment: not out of the box, you might could add manually